# C++/CLI Visual C++ 2010 Express - Drawing multiple ellipses

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, drawing

I want to draw multiple filled ellipses on/in some panel. Drawing single one isnt problem, i am using:

```
Color aColor = Color::FromArgb( 255, 0, 0 ); 
SolidBrush^ aBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(aColor);
Rectangle rect = Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
e->Graphics->FillEllipse(aBrush, rect);
```

It draws red ellipse bordered by rectangle, and fills it with red color. (assuming i will give `x` and `y`). The problem i met, is when I want to draw multiple ellipses like that, in RANDOM places. So i need to pass random `x` and `y` (using `rand()` % somenumber) but i am not sure, how can i pass these variables into the `panel1_paint` function and draw them when both numbers are randomized. Also, ofc i dont want the last ellipse to disappear when drawing new one. The only way is using global variables?

Any ideas?

Well, i tried as suggested, to use loop inside panel and i got that:

```
for(int i=0; i<ile_przeszkod; i++){
int x = rand() % 690; int y = rand() % 690;
Color aColor = Color::FromArgb( 255, 0, 0 ); 
SolidBrush^ aBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(aColor);
Rectangle rect = Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
e->Graphics->FillEllipse(aBrush, rect);
MessageBox::Show("x: "+x+ " y: " +y);
}
```

ile_przeszkod means how many of them i want to be drawn, and message box showes me what numbers it randomized so i am sure ellipses dont overlap. The problem is, after "invalidating" panel1 i see only 1 ellipse. :/ What should i do to see both of them?

Comment: What's the deciding factor of multiple `x`, `y` points ?

Comment: Well, x and y are cords of point, where rectangle should start. And i want to change them however i want, giving them some numbers i want, or just randomizing them, to get these ellipses be drawn all over the place, randomly.

Comment: So If x, y s are all random why do you need to pass them to panel1_paint ? instead you can generate a series of random number in panel1_paint and loop them to pain ellipse

Comment: Tried that now, but i met another problem, i see only 1 of the elipses, not both. (when doing that for loop twice). Edited my question ^ with code of my try.

Comment: Bah, got it working. Thanks. You can write it as answer if you want, so i will be able to accept it.

Comment: Do the MessageBox Fires multiple times ? and what is the value of `ile_przeszkod` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the `x, y` coordinates are random , so they don't depend on some other deciding procedure, So that need not to be passed to `panel1_paint` rather you can run a lpop and generate random number to use them as your `x`, `y` coordinates.